# Show that $|A_{ij}| \leq \|A\|_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{n\times m}$, show that each entry is bounded by the maximum singular value:

$$|A_{ij}| \leq \|A\|_2$$

**my attempt**

$$|A_{ij}| = |\langle A, e_ie_j^T\rangle| = |\langle U \Sigma V^T, e_ie_j^T|$$

where we have used the SVD of $A$ and written $e_i$ for the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^d$.

Then, by properties of the trace inner product:

$$=|\langle \Sigma, Ve_ie_j^TU^T\rangle|$$

Since $U, V$ are orthogonal matrices, they are rotations. So the following upper bound holds:

$$\leq \sup_{M}|\langle \Sigma, M\rangle|$$

where the supremum is taken over matrices with rank at most 2 and frobenius norm at most 1.

But this supremum is obviously the maximum singular value of $A$.

**My question**

Is the last step really "obvious"? I guess it relies on the supremum over rank 1 matrices being equal to the supremum over rank 2 matrices (in the case where we are limited to frobenius norm 1), but this seems counterintuitive to me.

Comment: It is simpler than that. Note that for any unit vectors $u,v$ you have $|u^T Av| \le \|u\|\|A\| \|v\| =\|A\|$. Note choose $u,v$ appropriately.

Comment: Also, note that $\langle A, e_i e_j^T \rangle_F = e_i^TA e_j = [A]_{ij}$.

Comment: Dont i need my last step to show your inequality?